# Helm can't handle ConfigMap.mapRoles.username : system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have a kubernetes cluster that I'm now migrating to Helm. Cluster is running under AWS managed service AWS EKS.

Since AWS EKS by default creates only 1 user in the cluster (system.master) which is the AWS User who created the cluster. Having said that, in order to create another user to the cluster, I wound need to create a config map below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/terraform-eks-main-node
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
  mapUsers: | 
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:user/admin-access 
      username: admin-access 
      groups: 
        - system:masters
```

running the configmap using helm causes issues due to `{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}`. Is there any proper way to handle it?

Comment: As in, the YAML file you're trying to deploy to Kubernetes needs to contain the literal string `{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}`, including the curly braces?  Or are you trying to pass that as a configurable parameter?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy with the {{EC2PrivateDNSName}} as is, there are no variable to interpolate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever Helm (and the embedded Go `text/template` engine) sees `{{`, it interprets it as a template variable expansion.  If you want to include those characters literally in the output, you need a template expression that generates them; for example

```yaml
username: system:node:{{ "{{" }}EC2PrivateDNSName}}
```

Comment: Template:
username: {{ .Values.nodeRoleUsername }}

Values: nodeRoleUsername: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}